# PHP Connect and Insert Data to RDS MySQL AWS

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services

Hi I am trying to connect and insert data into an RDS MySQL database created on amazon aws using a simple PHP script. I can connect it to MySQL Workbench using host/endpoint username, password etc. However when I try connecting it using php using the following code:

```
<?php
$dbname = "database_name";
$dbuser = "database_user"; 
$dbpass = "database_password"; 
$dbhost01 = "user.regioninfo.rds.amazonaws.com"; 
$dbport = 3306;

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost01;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);


?>
```

Now when I upload this elastic beanstalk on AWS and when I run it I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'user.regioninfo.rds.amazonaws.com' (110 "Connection timed out")
```

Anybody struggled with similar issue please let me know as I am new to AWS and I want to create a simple PHP script to push data to the RDS mySQL database in AWS. Thanks..

Comment: Have you followed the steps outlined [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html) to allow your beanstalk application to talk to RDS?

Comment: Open the security group assigned to the RDS instance accordingly, to allow access from the Elastic Beanstalk servers. If you aren't sure how to do that, start by including the current security group rules in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The security group is set to: default (sg-e465c88c) (vpc-0338146a)

Comment: Silly question, but I assume the database variables are examples that you're showing and not the *actual* code, right? Looking at your error, you don't seem to have changed it from the example... Also, the security group means little to us, but you need to make sure the outgoing port is authorized.

Comment: Yeah I have not put the right details in the code above but in the actual script I did. I'll look into the security groups and outgoing port to make sure everything is configured properly. Thanks